# ¿Cómo seleccionar un campo cuyo valor es de tipo TIMESTAMP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo en una variable `$mon`, el día que es el lunes en formato `YYYY-mm-dd`

```
$mon = $yeararray[0].'-'.sprintf('%02d',$montharray[0]).'-'.sprintf('%02d',$daysarray[0]);
```

Este código me muestra `2017-05-29`

Tengo que hacer una consulta sql que determine si el día (`day`) especificado en mi base de datos es el mismo que `$mon`.

He probado de esta forma, donde `day` es un campo de tipo TIMESTAMP:

```
$mon_consulta = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE date(day) = $mon";
```

Parece que no funciona y no me avanza.

Comment: Para que funcione el formato de tu campo date(day) debería ser "DATE", ¿cuál es? En función del formato se haría de un modo u otro

Comment: Es `TIMESTAMP` mi campo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería más o menos asi:

```
$mon_consulta = " SELECT * FROM $dbTable
WHERE date(day) LIKE '".$mon."%' ";
```

Para que compare con la primera parte del timestamp que equivale a la fecha.
Espero que te sirva.